# Awesome WM adding a keybinding to the Super_L key blocks other key commands from working properly

Tags: lua, awesome-wm

I'm trying to implement some Super-Tab functionality into `awesome-wm` so that it acts in a similar way to alt tab, going through tags in order of last used rather than just a set order.

However I've run into an issue, which is that binding something to only `Super_L` will cause other keybinds to not work as before.

For testing right now I just have it set to this

```
awful.key({}, "Super_L",  function () naughty.notify{text = "aaa"} end,  function () naughty.notify{text = "bbb"} end)
```

The issue is that if I have this set, then a key binding like `Super-Shift-C` (to close the current window) doesn't work, at least not if you press it in that order. It will work if you press it `Shift-Super-C`.

Is there a reason for this/a way to fix it?

**Extra question**: *Why doesn't the key release function work, when I press Super_L with this awful.key setting you would expect it to show "aaa" when I press, and "bbb" when I release, but only "aaa" shows up.*

I'm not super sure what to try, I've been messing around with the key configs and can't figure out what's going on.

Some of the Super key bindings still work, like `Super-H` to change the size of a window in tiling mode.

Answer (score 0):

There's some way to make your code work, but more generally, this is not the best way to implement `Super-Tab`. The easier way is to use [`awful.keygrabber`](https://awesomewm.org/apidoc/core_components/awful.keygrabber.html).

```lua
awful.keygrabber {
    keybindings = {
        awful.key {
            modifiers = {"Mod4"},
            key       = "Tab",
            on_press  = function () naughty.notify{text = "aaa"} end
        },
        awful.key {
            modifiers = {"Mod4", "Shift"},
            key       = "Tab",
            on_press  = function () naughty.notify{text = "ccc"} end
        },
    },
    stop_key           = "Super_L",
    stop_event         = "release",
    start_callback     = function () naughty.notify{text = "ddd"} end,
    stop_callback      = function () naughty.notify{text = "bbb"} end,
    export_keybindings = true,
}
```

This code (cop pasted from the doc link above) will create 2 keybindings (`Super_L+Tab` and `Super_L+Shift+Tab`). However, once one is executed, instead of just calling the callback, it will start to grab all keys. When `Super_L` is released, it will stop the keygrabber.

Comment: Thanks for the code, I tried adding it to my rc.lua but I am getting an error "/usr/share/awesome/lib/awfulkeygrabber.lua:821: attempt to concatenate a nil value
I just added it inside my globalkeys = gears.table.join( section, not sure if that is the right place to add it

Comment: add it at the bottom of rc.lua, not in the key section

Comment: I added it right at the end but I'm still getting the error. I can't copy it into text as when you click it disappears in awesome but here is a screenshot of it: https://imgur.com/a/UzdHTNa

Comment: I can confirm the code above works with the git-master version of AwesomeWM. I didn't try with v4.3. Also, you seem to have 2 different problems in your error log.

Comment: I can't get the git version to work because of the issue described here: https://awesomewm.org/download/ under the "Building from source" section. Is the syntax required for the keygrabber different between versions? 

(The second error I think was just from something else)

Comment: The API is the same as far as I remember, but a few bugs were solved. Also, if you are on Arch, Gentoo or a few other, they provide packages for git-master. For Ubuntu/Debian, you can run `make packages` to generate them.

Comment: I got it to stop giving me an error on the git version, using `make packages` worked thanks. The keygrabber bit appears to be working now (the "aaa" "bbb" popups are appearing), however it has stopped most other `super-X` keybindings working. For example Super-E to open file manager or Super-Ctrl-R to reload awesome no longer work.